# How to load the AAudio API for Android using ndk

Tags: c++, android-ndk

I would like to know how to load the AAudio API using ndk, I tried some links:

https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/audio
https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/audio/aaudio/aaudio

but here it just tells me how to use it and I didn't find anything about adding to Android.mk

Any lib to be loaded? What should I do?

```
#include <AAudio.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

hi man you should add this in your CMakeList.txt

```
find_library(AAudio-lib AAudio)

target_link_libraries(
    ....
    ${AAudio-lib}
)
```

hope this will help have a nice day of cod ^^

Comment: Great! You might want to do `find_library(AAudio-lib AAudio REQUIRED)`